# Haskell "The type variable `a0' is ambiguous" Error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function for this series.

[image: Cos Series]

Code is here:

```
fact x = product [1..x]

cosSeries x l = sum[(helperOfCos x i pointer)
        |i<-[0..l], i `mod` 2 == 0, pointer<-[0..l]]


helperOfCos x i p = if p `mod` 2 == 0
        then x**i/(fact i)
        else -(x**i)/(fact i)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
*Main> cosSeries 2 2

<interactive>:2:1:
No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of `cosSeries'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  instance Integral GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
In the expression: cosSeries 2 2
In an equation for `it': it = cosSeries 2 2

<interactive>:2:11:
No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `2'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus three others
In the first argument of `cosSeries', namely `2'
In the expression: cosSeries 2 2
In an equation for `it': it = cosSeries 2 2
```

I couldn't understand solution of similar questions in stackoverflow.

Can you help me about that error?

Thanks..

Comment: to make your errors clearer start by adding explicit type signatures - what input are your functions expecting - what output are you expecting. note haskell has no automatic type conversion - you need to explicitly call `fromIntegral` if you want to have an `Int` used as a `Double`

Comment: also note there are functions `odd` and `even`

Comment: We really need MathJax support. The formula is barely readable.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe thank you for your answers. I tried chi's answer which is the same logic with yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always add signatures, for better errors.

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact x = product [1..x]

cosSeries :: Double -> Int -> Double
cosSeries x l = sum[(helperOfCos x i pointer)
        |i<-[0..l], i `mod` 2 == 0, pointer<-[0..l]]


helperOfCos :: Double -> Int -> Int -> Double
helperOfCos x i p = if p `mod` 2 == 0
        then x^i / fromIntegral (fact i)
        else -(x^i) / fromIntegral (fact i)
```

Here the problem was the lack of the last two `fromIntegral`. Indeed, `fact i` returned an integral type (since `mod` above forces `i` to be integral), but `/` requires a floating type.

Without the conversion, we would get a type with an unsatisfiable constraint:

```
> :t cosSeries 
cosSeries :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a
```

Also note that `fact` will quickly generate very large numbers and cause overflows. You can prevent that using `Integer` instead of `Int`, or reworking your code so to avoid computing the factorial at each step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like a charm!
I'm trying to understand the logic of Haskell. It helped so much!